# List append MemoryError

Tags: python, list, memory, append

So I have this piece of code I'm trying to make generate level layouts for a grid of rooms. The first time through the mainloop it runs perfectly it runs and does exactly what it should but the second time through it pauses just after the first print error and gives me the attached error and I cant figure out what's wrong with it.
(the y/n prompt is only to slow down the program so I can see what's happening)

```
userInput = ""

roomChance = 0.5

world = [[0,0,0], \
         [0,1,0], \
         [0,0,0]]

possibleWorld = []

newX = []


def check_neighbours(xy):
    possibleWorld.clear()
    yLoops = 0
    for y in xy:
        print("  y:", y)
        xLoops = 0
        for x in y:
            print("  x:", x)

            #Check left cell
            if(xLoops-1 >= 0):
                if(y[xLoops-1] == 1):
                    possibleWorld.append([xLoops, yLoops])
                print("x-1:", y[xLoops-1])

            #Check right cell
            if(xLoops+1 < len(y)):
                if(y[xLoops+1] == 1):
                    possibleWorld.append([xLoops, yLoops])
                print("x+1:", y[xLoops+1])

            #Check above cell
            if(yLoops-1 >= 0):
                if(xy[yLoops-1][xLoops] == 1):
                    possibleWorld.append([xLoops, yLoops])
                print("y-1:", xy[yLoops-1][xLoops])

            #Check above cell
            if(yLoops+1 < len(xy)):
                if(xy[yLoops+1][xLoops] == 1):
                    possibleWorld.append([xLoops, yLoops])
                print("y+1:", xy[yLoops+1][xLoops])            


            print("\n")

            xLoops += 1

        yLoops += 1

def assign_neighbours(possible, world, chance):
    for i in possible:
        if(random.random() < chance):
            world[i[1]][i[0]] = 1
    possible.clear()

def border_expand(world):

    for x in world[0]:
        if(x == 1):
            for i in world[0]:
                newX.append(0)
            world.insert(0, newX)
            newX.clear
            break


def print_world(world):
    for y in world:
        print(y)


# ==================== Mainloop ====================
while(True):

    userInput = input(print("Generate Level? Y/N?"))    

    check_neighbours(world)

    print(possibleWorld)

    assign_neighbours(possibleWorld, world, roomChance)

    print_world(world)

    border_expand(world)

    print("\n")

    print_world(world)
```

````
  File "C:\Users\Potato\Desktop\Level gen_query.py", line 96, in <module>
    border_expand(world)
  File "C:\Users\Potato\Desktop\Level gen_query.py", line 67, in border_expand
    newX.append(0)
MemoryError```
````

Comment: The error is telling you you are using too much memory. Note, `newX.clear` doesn't do anything, you probably want `newX.clear()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, this is what the issue was, cheers for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling `newX.clear`, so it is continually growing. When you run `world.insert(0, newX)` you are inserting a reference to `newX` into `world[0]`, even if you did call `newX.clear()` you would not get the behaviour you want as the first element in `world` would be empty.

You need to create a new list on every call to `border_expand` so that it is a new list every time

```
def border_expand(world):
    newX = []
    for x in world[0]:
        if(x == 1):
            for i in world[0]:
                newX.append(0)
            world.insert(0, newX)
            break
```